# Sudden shower pressure drop

Tags: plumbing, shower

A couple weeks ago, the shower pressure we have dropped. I didn't notice it at first — it wasn't a major change — but after my spouse pointed it out, it's definitely lower than it was.

I've tried fixing several of the common problems.

- I made sure the shower head and hand-held hose were clean and not blocked.
- I replaced the pressure-balancing valve with a new one, and made sure the inlets/outlets were clean.
- I replaced the bathtub diverter.
- I tried cleaning out (with a drain snake) the supply lines, but the turns were too tight to get much of anywhere. Nothing was obviously dirty.
- I tried pouring vinegar into the shower pipe while plugging the tub diverter, but I only left it for an hour or so — is that worth trying again overnight?

I've tested the water pressure, and found that the pressure coming to the house is about 60 psi (right in line with what the city provides) and the pressure coming out of the shower spigot is about 5-10 psi lower than that. (That sounds normal?)

The pressure does not seem to be appreciably different with hot or cold water.

I've compared the flow rate (by timing filling an ice cream bucket) from the shower spigot — without the head or hose attached — and the tub spigot. The shower spigot took several more seconds to fill the bucket on repeated measurements.

I haven't noticed any other changes in the water supply in the house — but I suppose that the change was small enough that perhaps we only notice in the shower?

I, unfortunately, do not have any measurements for either pressure or flow rate from before we noticed the problem, so it's a bit hard to tell what is "normal" and what, exactly, has changed.

My next idea is to try back-flush the shower by:

1. Keeping the supply valve off.
2. Connecting a water supply to the shower spigot.
3. Letting water flow from the shower spigot down to the tub spigot, hoping that something might wash out.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I assume the 60 psi pressure you measured coming in to the house was after the pressure regulating valve (PRV). You said the 60 psi is right in line with what the city provides but you should have a PRV. Typically curb pressure from city systems is over 100 psi. This fluctuates sometimes as new construction goes up in the area or work is done on the city system. But if your PRV is working properly you shouldn't be affected by minor changes in curb pressure. How old is the PRV? They will sometimes fail over time.

Comment: @HoneyDo I’ve looked for a PRV, but haven’t seen one anywhere. Are they common in all areas? I live in Fargo, ND.

Comment: But the only different is the shower rate of flow verses the tub faucet, with the shower flow being slower.  Water pressure to the house would affect all fixtures, not just one.

Comment: Right. The pipes are behind the wall, so I can’t look at the pipe size, but is it normal for the shower flow to be lower than the tub?

Comment: Not all water systems have PRVs - don't know about Fargo. The best way to know is to call your water supplier. PRVs are typically located around your main shutoff but they could be almost at any point along the main coming into the house.

Comment: If the flow from the shower spigot without the fixture attached is slower by several seconds in filling the ice bucket (assume about 1 gal), I would not consider that as normal.  You have replaced the diverter.  My best guess is a blockage in the pipe that feeds the shower.  Your idea of back flushing through the shower spigot appears to be the best next step.

Comment: @HoneyDo I’ll check with the city about the PRV. Even if not the problem here, I’d still like to know. Thanks!

Comment: @Programmer66 I'll try that as soon as the adapter I need comes in the mail. Thank you!